# Alertdialog push message is not changing, always the first one

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

this is my first time posting a question, i hope to do it well. Im making an android app and one of the things i'm implementing, is that when a notification comes and if i selected on the notification bar, it show me an alertdialog with the message, the first time works, but when i send other message, it always shows the first message send it.

This is the code im using on a *GCMIntentService*:

```
private void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

    varDb =new VSCSQLiteHelper(context, "Probe1", null, 1);

    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

    if(tts == null) {
        tts = new TextToSpeech(this.getApplicationContext(), this);
    }

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    hora = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

    db = varDb.getWritableDatabase();   
    config = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Config_prob1",null); 
    config.moveToFirst();

    if(hora >= config.getInt(2) && hora <= config.getInt(3)){

        if(config.getInt(0) == 1 && config.getInt(1) == 1){
            notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Mensaje.class);   
            notificationIntent.putExtra("message", message);  
            tts.speak(message, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);

            // set intent so it does not start a new activity
            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            PendingIntent intent =
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

            // Play default notification sound
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

            // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
            notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

        }else if(config.getInt(1) == 1){
            notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Mensaje.class);   
            notificationIntent.putExtra("message", message);  
            // set intent so it does not start a new activity
            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            PendingIntent intent =
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

            // Play default notification sound
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

            // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
            notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
        }else{
            tts.speak(message, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);   
        }
    }       
    config.close();
    db.close(); 
}
```

and for the class that shows the message i have:

```
public class Mensaje extends Activity{

 private Bundle bundle = null;
 private String mensaje = "";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mensaje); 

    bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    mensaje = bundle.getString("message");         

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Mensaje.this);
    builder.setMessage(mensaje)
            .setTitle("Mensaje recibido")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.logo)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setNeutralButton("Aceptar",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.dismiss();                                   
                            Mensaje.this.finish();
                        }
                    });
    builder.create();
    builder.show();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.i("Mensaje", "onDestroy()");
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

I tried to print the message, the message that came on de *GCMIntent* is fine but in the other class is always the first one.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `PendingIntent` to look like this:

```
PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

That way your `Intent` will always refresh it's values from the ones you provided from the notification.