# Multiple simultaneous notifications with Cordova PushPlugin v2.4.0 on Android

Tags: android, cordova, notifications

I have implemented the PushPlugin for Android and iOS, and most things are working fine.
On iOS everything is perfect. ON Android with the app in the foreground too.

But I have a problem on Android when my app is in the background (or cold-started), and there are multiple notifications queued in the Android status bar. No matter which notification the user taps, the app always gets the top one in the list sent to it.

This is kind of similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24939454/alertdialog-push-message-is-not-changing-always-the-first-one) (even if it is not using Cordova/PushPlugin), but I have checked the [source code](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/blob/master/src/android/com/plugin/gcm/GCMIntentService.java) of the plugin, and it is using the `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` flag as per that issues solution, but the problem persists for me.

If anyone has succeeded in getting this to run I would be grateful for any tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... It seems the problem is caused by a bug in the PushPlugin.

As described in the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html), multiple PendingIntents needs to have something separating them from each other, otherwise they are all treated as the same.

There is already [a pull request on the plugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/pull/333) fixing this, which uses the `notId` parameter as `requestCode`. This solved the problem for me too.